# ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis ,maybe problem with SubQuery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This Query give an error

> ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis

I can't find any parenthesis problem

```
   select 
    (select PRE_DESIG_ID FROM AUTHORIZATION 
         WHERE PROJECT_ID = 5 and PRE_DESIG_ID =48 and 
    ROWNUM=1 order by ID DESC) AS PERPARED_BY
    ,(Select PRE_LAST_DATE From (Select PRE_LAST_DATE From AUTHORIZATION  
    Where PROJECT_ID = 5 and PRE_DESIG_ID = 48 Order By ID Desc) 
    Where ROWNUM = 1) AS PRE_END_DT from AUTHORIZATION au
    LEFT join PROJECT p on AU.PROJECT_ID =p.PROJECT_ID
    LEFT join DESIGNATION d on au.AU_DESIG_ID=d.DESIGID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

`ORDER BY id DESC`

You can't use `ORDER BY` in a  subquery that acts as a column expression. If you remove it the error you're facing will go away.

But, I would prefer you rewrite your query using a `with` clause, since both of your sub-query expression fetches the same row.

```
WITH auth AS ( SELECT *
                 FROM ( SELECT pre_desig_id AS perpared_by,
                    pre_last_date AS pre_end_dt
                        FROM authorization
                      WHERE project_id = 5
          AND pre_desig_id = 48 ORDER BY id DESC )
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1 )
SELECT a.perpared_by,a.pre_end_dt
  FROM authorization au
  LEFT JOIN project p ON au.project_id = p.project_id
  LEFT JOIN designation d ON au.au_desig_id = d.desigid
 CROSS JOIN auth a;
```

Comment: And for those on 12.1 or later, `fetch first row only` makes a lot of this complication go away.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the derived column's (`prepared_by`) subquery similar to `pre_end_dt`'s subquery as below

```
Select 
       (Select pre_desig_id
          From (Select pre_desig_id,
                       row_number() over (order by ID desc) as rn
                  From Authorization
                 Where project_id = 5
                   and pre_desig_id = 48
                 )
         Where rn = 1)  as prepared_by,
       (Select pre_last_date
          From (Select pre_last_date,
                       row_number() over (order by ID desc) as rn
                  From Authorization
                 Where project_id = 5
                   and pre_desig_id = 48
                 )
         Where rn = 1) as pre_end_dt
  From Authorization au
  Left Join Project p
    on au.project_id = p.project_id
  Left Join Designation d
    on au.au_desig_id = d.desigid;
```

where `Order By ID Desc` part produces the error, that should be wrapped within an extra subquery, otherwise compiler doesn't allow to use `Order By` directly as this. i.e. restriction (`rownum=1`) and using `order by` are not allowed to work at the same level, they need to exist within outer, and inner select statements respectively.

In fact, it's better to use `row_number()` window analytic function rather than `rownum` pseudocolumn, which is untrustable for most cases since it is generated before sorting.

Even if using `Where rownum = 1` with `order by ID desc` for inner select statement is enough for you to use, rather make an habit using `row_number()` function.